# plus, minus in cart page

Tags: cart, ajax, shopping-cart, magento2.3.3, ajaxaddtocart

I have the following design below, in which it has plus and minus on the **cart page** and **mini cart** page.

[image: specimen cart page]

I have achieved it in minicart but **couldn't achieve it on the cart page**.

can someone help to achieve this solution?

Comment: what version of magento? 2?

Comment: its magento 2.3.3 @Barry

Comment: Can you try my code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**For the cart page**

First, override this file in your module or theme **Path: vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/item/default.phtml**

> Find the element `<div class="control qty">` and replace it with below
>   code

```
<div class="control qty">
    <input id="cart-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>-qty"
           name="cart[<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>][qty]"
           data-cart-item-id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getSku() ?>"
           value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getQty() ?>"
           type="number"
           size="4"
           title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?>"
           class="input-text qty"
           data-validate="{required:true,'validate-greater-than-zero':true}"
           data-role="cart-item-qty"/>
    <div class="qty_control">
        <button type="button"  id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>-upt" class="increaseQty">+</button>
        <button type="button"   id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>-dec"  class="decreaseQty">-</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

and add below script in the last

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["jquery"],function($){
        $('#<?php echo $_item->getId();?>-upt, #<?php echo $_item->getId();?>-dec').on("click",function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            var ctrl = ($(this).attr('id').replace('-upt','')).replace('-dec','');
            var currentQty = $("#cart-"+ctrl+"-qty").val();
            if($this.hasClass('increaseQty')){
                var newAdd = parseInt(currentQty)+parseInt(1);
                $("#cart-"+ctrl+"-qty").val(newAdd);
            }else{
                if(currentQty>1){
                    var newAdd = parseInt(currentQty)-parseInt(1);
                    $("#cart-"+ctrl+"-qty").val(newAdd);
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**For mini cart**

Override this file in your module or your theme **Path: vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html**

> Find the element `<div class="details-qty qty">` and replace it with
>   below code

```
<div class="details-qty qty">
    <label class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Qty', attr: {
           for: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty'}"></label>
    <div class="more">+</div>
    <input data-bind="attr: {
           id: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty',
           'data-cart-item': item_id,
           'data-item-qty': qty,
           'data-cart-item-id': product_sku
           }, value: qty"
           type="number"
           size="4"
           class="item-qty cart-item-qty">
    <div class="less">-</div>
    <button data-bind="attr: {
           id: 'update-cart-item-'+item_id,
           'data-cart-item': item_id,
           title: $t('Update')
           }"
            class="update-cart-item"
            style="display: none">
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Update'"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

**Path: vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/minicart.phtml**

Put this code in last

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["jquery"],function($){
        $('body').on("click",".more, .less",function(){
            var obj = $(this);
            var currentQty = obj.siblings('.cart-item-qty').val();
            var iid = obj.siblings('.update-cart-item').attr('data-cart-item');

            if(obj.hasClass('more')){
                var newAdd = parseInt(currentQty)+parseInt(1);
                obj.siblings('.cart-item-qty').val(newAdd);
                obj.siblings('.cart-item-qty').attr('data-item-qty',newAdd);
                $('.update-cart-item').show();
            }else{
                if(parseInt(currentQty) > 1)
                {
                    var newAdd = parseInt(currentQty)-parseInt(1);
                    obj.siblings('.cart-item-qty').val(newAdd);
                    obj.siblings('.cart-item-qty').attr('data-item-qty',newAdd);
                    $('.update-cart-item').show();

                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Note: Run all necessary CLI commands
Ex.

- php bin/magento setup:upgrade
- php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
- php bin/magento cache:clean

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @RamalakshmiT if my answer solved your concern then please mark as accepted by clicking on ✓ icon next to my answer

Comment: Its working fine.but i am also need some changes.

Comment: @RamalakshmiT Okay, First please mark as accepted by clicking on ✓ the icon next to my answer and please ask a new question regarding the new changes!

Comment: @ Vithal Bariya Every time when I increase the quantity or decrease and when i press enter only the price gets updated and page also gets reloaded.

Comment: Mini cart or cart page?

Comment: I checked my code and it's working fine

Comment: In cart page @ Vithal Bariya

Comment: If i increasing the qty and automatically price gets updated without press enter and reloaded.
This is my addinational requirement.@Vithal Bariya
But above code,If i increase or decrease the quantity and when i press enter only the price gets updated.
If you have any idea about that,please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. @Vithal Bariya